# Table data is not editable at this location, why won't this checkbox let me check it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

```
f = figure;
 columnname = {'X' , 'Y'};
 Selection = {'A','B','C','D','E'}
[vals{1:numel(Selection),1}]=deal(false)
    columnform = {'logical','logical'};
t = uitable('Data',vals,'ColumnName', columnname, 'ColumnFormat', columnform,'ColumnEdit',[true true true], 'RowName', Selection);
```

If you run this script it should spit out a figure. but i can only select the checkboxes in the X column of the table. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tha's because the variable `vals` does not contain sufficient data to fill the table.

Simple replicate it to form a 2-column array and it works. i.e. add this line:

```
vals = [vals vals]
```

before creating the table.

Whole code:

```
f = figure;
close all
clc
clear

columnname = {'X' , 'Y'};
Selection = {'A','B','C','D','E'}
[vals{1:numel(Selection),1}]=deal(false);

vals = [vals vals]

columnform = {'logical','logical'};

t = uitable('Data',vals,'ColumnName', columnname, 'ColumnFormat', columnform, 'RowName', Selection,'ColumnEdit',true(1,2*size(Selection,1)));
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

To get indices of selected cells you don't need to specifically add new variables.

By setting the `CellSelectionCallback` you can fetch the indices directly.

Let's say you add this line after creating the table:

```
set(t,'CellSelectionCallback',@SelCB)
```

Then the function can be used to get indices as follows:

```
function SelCB(~, event)

    SelectedCells = event.Indices        
 end
```

Which will output a 1x2 element vector each time a cell is selected/deselected.

Comment: thanks for the help, how do I resize the columns so that they fit to the data and there isn't that large blank space on the right and bottom? Also is there a way to have only 1 box checked per column at a time or will i have to switch to radio buttons for that?

Comment: I can change the column width for the individual variables like x and y just fine, but that blank space jsut wont leave or automatically resize. I'll keep looking I guess.

Comment: It looks like you can adjust the table position using a 4-element vector `[x y width height]` using `set(t,'Position',[])`